# Riak KV returns 403 Forbidden when it's behing reverse proxy

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, http-status-code-403, riak

I'm getting 403 Forbidden from RiakKV, which is behind reverse proxy, when trying to reach it from my frontend (I'm making a request from Angular http client). The strange thing about it is that when I'm trying to run the same GET request from Postman (or even from web browser entering direct url to the Riak API), there is no problem - I'm getting data.

I analized Riak's logs and figured out that it is related with referrer header "request denied due to invalid referrer".
As it is stated in Riak's documentation (http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.3/configuring/reference/):

> Some reverse proxies cannot remove the Referer header and make
>   serving data directly from Riak impossible. Turning this setting
>   [secure_referer_check] to off disables this security check.

I disabled this option and it works fine.

But I'm wondering is it possible to achieve this without turning this option off (as I understand, it increases security), modifying proxy settings.

My proxy is configured on Apache HTTP Server and looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <LocationMatch "/riak">
            ProxyPass "http://IP:8098/"
            ProxyPassReverse "http://IP:8098/"
            Header add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "https://my.domain"
        </LocationMatch>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I was experimenting with options

```
Header add referer ""
RequestHeader set referer ""
```

to unset referer, but it didn't work.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try `Header unset referer`?

Comment: It worked! Precisely it should be `RequestHeader unset "Referer"
`. Thanks a lot